# PHP Multidimensional Array: Extract parent array when element value has unique ID

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array with an unknown number of levels. If a child array element contains a unique value, then how do I extract the parent array for use in PHP?

My array looks similar to this, except I don't know how may grandparents the key/value has (or this would be a lot easier).

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [blockName] => core/group,
        [attrs] => Array ( ),

        [innerBlocks] => Array
            (
                // I want to extract this array if its [attrs] element contains [wrapper-id] => myUniqueID
                // The number of parents and grandparents is unknown. This is only an example.
                // Notice that other arrays contain attrs elements, but the value of this one is unique.
                [0] => Array 
                    (
                        [blockName] => lazyblock/zurb-tabs-wrapper,
                        [attrs] => Array
                            (
                                [wrapper-id] => myUniqueID, // This unique ID value is known.
                                [blockId] => T,
                                [blockUniqueClass] => lazyblock-zurb-tabs-wrapper-T
                            ),
                        [innerBlocks] => Array ()
                    ),
                // Later, I'll also want to extract this array based on its unique wrapper-id class.
                [1] => Array 
                    (
                        [blockName] => lazyblock/zurb-tabs-wrapper,
                        [attrs] => Array
                            (
                                [wrapper-id] => anotherUniqueID, // This unique ID value is known.
                                [blockId] => T,
                                [blockUniqueClass] => lazyblock-zurb-tabs-wrapper-T
                            ),
                        [innerBlocks] => Array ()
                    )
            )
    )
```

)

Finding the path to the parent might also work so I can walk to the values I need without extracting. That solution is [similar to this getkeypath() function from Drummin](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/find-path-of-the-given-array-key/42633) , except the author is matching a key instead of a value. This is a problem for me because my key is is not unique, but my value is.

Comment: Is this array generated from the SimpleXML dump of an HTML page or something?

Comment: @AlexHowansky It is a custom WordPress block. I am getting the post content. I want to access the array from a PHP block template. My users can embed this block in other blocks. That's why I don't know how many grandparents it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive function is definitely the way to go with an unknown number of parents.

```php
function getBlock(array $blocks, string $id): ?array
{
    foreach ($blocks as $block)
    {
        // if the block has a wrapper-id attr and it matches the requested id, return it
        if (!empty($block['attrs']['wrapper-id']) && $block['attrs']['wrapper-id'] === $id)
        {
            return $block;
        }

        // check if we have inner blocks to iterate
        if (!empty($block['innerBlocks']))
        {
            $innerBlock = getBlock($block['innerBlocks'], $id);
            if (!empty($innerBlock)) {
                return $innerBlock;
            }
        }
    }

    // fallback empty response
    return null;
}
```

Then you'll call the `getBlock` method with your parent array.

```php
$block = getBlock($blocks);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a fancier way to do this, and it doesn't return the key chain/path to the found child, but this code will return the matching child array:

```
function findChild($a, $fieldName, $fieldValue)
{
    $result = null;

    if (is_array($a)) {
        if (isset($a[$fieldName]) && $a[$fieldName] === $fieldValue) {
            $result = $a;
        } else {
            foreach ($a as $subA) {
                $result = findChild($subA, $fieldName, $fieldValue);
                if ($result) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$matchingChildOrNull = findChild($data, 'wrapper-id', 5678);
```

Comment: This is helpful because it shows the path to the child, but I'm trying to then move up one level to return the parent. Xengulai's answer is working as expected.